# Razor MVC 4 only displaying one of multiple uploaded files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, file-io

I'm trying to upload multiple files, the dialog shows multiple files selected (pictured below), but only the first file gets stored in my code. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.files, new { @class = "form-control", type = "file", multiple = "true", placeholder = "upload files"})
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "type,files,date")] Task mydata)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(mydata.files);//outputs: "C:\<path>\asdf.txt"
}
```

Edit: Task.files is of type string

Comment: What's the type of `Task.files`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When uploading multiple files, you want to bind to a collection. `IEnumerable<string>` should give you all filenames.

However, when uploading a file, the property should be a `HttpPostedFileBase`. When uploading multiple files, you need `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`.

Comment: Awesome, this works thanks! Upload may have been the wrong word. I just need the file location string because I'm doing the actual upload elsewhere in the code.